# All Angular-Datatables not render on project created

Tags: eclipse, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

All as table available are not rendering, I do not know if my error or documentation problem can not render follows the example I'm using:

```
ng new project
```

Create src/ files:

index.html:

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
<app-root> </app-root>
```

main.ts:

```
import { Component,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

@Component({
  selector: 'zero-config',
  templateUrl: 'index.html'
})


export class IndexComponent {}
```

The test realized in project was:

Zero configuration:
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/zero-config

Tks for any help.

Comment: where are you importing `DataTablesModule` Have you gone through the [Configuration steps](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) a lot of edits is required in your application Kindly go through the  Documentation https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: Yes, it was like I said I installed all the dependencies and settings I used from angular 6 and did not roll installed version 1.6.6 like this in the example, suddenly problem with compatibility and nothing. I imported the datatablemodule: @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      DataTablesModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  }) as you commented anyway so it was not. I do not know what it can be, can you help me?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4ff39 follow this and it should work

Comment: not rendered table